# pgAdmin connection in host machine to postgres in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, airflow, pgadmin

I have pgAdmin installed in my laptop. And postgres installed in docker container.
The postgres is setup in airflow docker image.

Now I am trying to connect to this postgres in pgAdmin in my laptop but getting this error:

```
Unable to connect to server: connection to server at "localhost" (::1),
O port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user
"airflow"
```

My docker-compose looks like this:

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    restart: always
```

I have tried putting the IP Address of the docker container but still same issue.

Comment: Look in the docker log for a more complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

For me the docker-compose file looks good.
Check your firewall maybe that block. Also check the connection between your computer and the docker server.

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.ipaddress}}{{end}}' postgres
```

this way you check your docker ip address make sure is correct.

I hope this helps.

( and of corse your password and username are correct )

Comment: IP, username, and password are correct.
How do I check firewall?
And connection between computer and docker containers?

Comment: The connection you can check with one ping. Open CMD, then write ping and the ip address. Firewall, you need to know what kind of firewall using ( windows, or any another ) they settings you see how who get access your computer. There need to check how you give permit to acess.